# Input stream reads and push backs by fscanf and scanf

Tags: c, scanf

Regarding `fscanf` (and I assume similarly for `scanf`), C17 7.21.6.2.9 states the following:

> "An input item is read from the stream...  An input item is defined as
> the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed any
> specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching
> input sequence.  The first character, if any, after the input item
> remains unread..."

Before reading this I had always assumed that the first character after the input item was read too, then pushed back.  For example, if the input was 5X and the conversion specification was `%d`, both the 5 and the X would be read but the X would be pushed back.  However, the quote above seems to indicate that each successive character in the input stream is being "peeked" at before it is read, so the X would never be read in the first place and a push back would never be necessary.  However, footnote 289 states that fscanf pushes back at most one input character onto the input stream.  So I guess my question is about what all of this really means.  Does "read" mean to remove a character from the stream or could it also mean to "peek" at a character without removing it?

Comment: There are cases where a single character isn't enough, and the result can be confusing. For example, `inf` is a legitimate value for `%f`, so if scanf sees an `i`, it looks at the next character to see if it's `n`. If not, two characters have been read but only one can be put back. Scanf returns a conversion error but the `i` disappears. (Similarly with `nan`.) So you can't reliably try to read a number and then fall back to reading a word. That will only work if the word does not start with `i` or `n`. Another case is `.` followed by a non-digit. Also, `2.0E-!`.

Answer (score 2):

Input stream can push back at least 1 character.

Scanning `"5X"` with `"%d"` results in `"5"` being read and converted to an `int 5`, then saved.  The `"X"` is read, but pushed back.

Trouble occurs with input like `"-a"` as the `"-"` is read and so is `"a"`.  C guarantees a successful push-back of `"a"`, but if `"-"` is successfully pushed back depends on the implementation.

```
int main() {
  int i;
  scanf("%d", &i);   // Enter -a
  printf("%c\n", getchar());
}
```

My output: `-`, not `a` as expected with only 1 push back.  YMMV.

This is one of the reasons that it is better to read a *line* of user input with `fgets()` into a *string* and then parse the string, than to use `(f)scanf()`.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"but if "-" is successfully pushed back depends on the implementation"` -- This statement seems contradictory to the [footnote mentioned in the question](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note285), which states that at most one character is pushed back. Maybe this footnote should be ignored, because [footnotes are not normative](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#Forewordp8). I am puzzled.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel As I read the spec and observe implementations, the footnote "fscanf pushes back at most one input character onto the input stream." is indeed amiss in "at most".  As I experience, it is more like "at least one".

Answer (score 1):

The pushback is not always necessary.  For example, if the conversion specification is `%3d` and the code reads three decimal digits successfully, it doesn't need to read anything more and there is no pushback.

The pushback is always the character that was read, so beyond recording where to read next, the input buffer doesn't need to change. (Using `ungetc()`, you can unget (push back) a character other than the one that was read.)

Reading a character means logically removing it from the stream.  If it isn't a usable character, it is pushed back, so the effect is the same as peeking.